# Equality of two series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Whan I was working with some series, I was confused by this problem. I have this serie:

$$A=2+\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-7}{4}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n-3}}-\sum_{k=\frac{n+1}{4}}^{ \frac{n-3}{2}}2\cos{\frac{k\pi}{n-3}}. $$
I changed the boundaries of the serie A (and also the variables) and obtained serie B:
$$B= \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-3}{4}}2\cos{\frac{(k-1)\pi}{n-3}}-\sum_{k=\frac{n+5}{4}}^{ \frac{n-1}{2}}2\cos{\frac{(k-1)\pi}{n-3}}$$
I thought A=B but by some computational softwares, I realized it's not correct. I can't find my mistakes. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which change of boundaries/variables did you make ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $\frac{n-7}{4}$ to $\frac{n-3}{4}$ or $k$ to $k-1$ and so on.

Comment: Everything looks fine, so indeed $A=B$. There must be a problem with your computational software (or with feeding it).